# Best fit line pass through origin for half normal plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I want to add a best fit line that pass through the origin for the half normal plot which plot in R by `fawaway` pacakage ,how can I do it?This is my half normal function:

```
test=aov(Thickness~A*B*C*D,data=dss)

halfnorm((test$effect[-1])/2, nlab= round(length(test$effects[-1])/3,0), labs= names(test$effects[-1]),
             ylab= "abs|Factor Effects|",
             main= "Half Normal Plot")
```

What should I write to draw the best fit line?

This is the image for halfnormal plot

[image]